# swift how to declare function with range argument

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, range, func

```
func forExample(arg1: int, arg2 <int range> (what here 1) ){
    
    print (arg2 what here 2)


}

forExamle(5, what here 3)
```

questions are three: how to declare range of INTs in the function brackets and how to ask it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague, but assuming you're looking for a closed range, you could do this:

```
func forExample(_ arg1: Int, _ arg2: ClosedRange<Int>){
    
    print ("\(arg1) \(arg2.lowerBound)-\(arg2.upperBound)")

}

forExample(5, 3...10)
```

Comment: is the ClosedRange is a regular word in swift?

Comment: What does "regular word" mean? If you mean is it included in the standard library: yes

Comment: `ClosedRange` is a type defined in the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
func forExample(arg1:Int, arg2:ClosedRange<Int>) {  
   print(arg2)
}
```

With

```
forExample(arg1: 12, arg2: 1...5)
```